# Read file and convert it to BitArray

Tags: c#, io, bitarray

I have the following problem. When I read file byte by byte and store the information in BitArray. The following BitArray does not have the true binary representation of the file.

This is my function which reads the file and convert it to BitArray:

```
public BitArray Read(string fileName){
        byte[] data;
        using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName)) {
            data = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        BitArray bitmap = new BitArray (data);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a byte array and then convert the array into a bitArray?

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: Well Erik thank you for your proposal. It is useful and will save some lines but it wont solve the problem which I have :)

Comment: Unless your *Read* method is throwing an exception, the BitArray *should* contain the true binary representation of the file. What exactly did you encounter as the content of the bit array?

Comment: Perhaps encoding types are giving you an issue, not sure what you mean by "not have the true binary representation of the file".

Comment: Well for example my true binary representation of the file (generated by C++ program and checked from the result - hex code) is:
- 000011000111000000100...
And what my BitArray stores is:
- 001100000000111011000...

Comment: hex-code only with "0" and "1"? And if it is indeed hex-code, why is it an odd number of digits (should it not be rather an even number of digits/nibbles)?

Comment: no I convert it to binary with calcolator

Comment: Hex code was invented to relieve us of reading 000111000111011

Comment: I guess your file content is not what you believe it is... (somewhere is a mistake...)

Comment: Thats what I have for hex code of the file:
040a 8880 51c0 and I convert it to binary on paper and its different from the things stored in my bitArray.

Comment: 040a 8880 51c0 is in binary: `00000100 00001010 10001000 10000000 01010001 11000000`. Look, this is different from what you told in your comment above. You need to double-check and rethink your procedures of (A) how you convert hex to binary correctly and (B) how you verify/read the actual content of the BitArray correctly...

Comment: Well sorry for that I take it from the middle of file...
Here you are a real example:
File with the following content - 0c70 2374 ...
Binary representation - 00001100011100000010001101110100 ...
And what my BitArray have - 001100000000111011000100001011101...

Comment: It is because of the way BitArray stores data. Please see my answer. The question asked by @NikolayTsonev is a valid one. It is indeed not intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that BitArray iterates bytes by least significant bit first because it is an array of bits.

See from [this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) the output of myBA3 bit array. You can find more info in the BitArray constructor [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a byte array.

Please note the comment in the ctor of the BitArray taking a byte array. You will see that it says: *The Least Significant Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value* This means that if you add an array of bytes [ 0x01 ,0x80 ] the iterating the bit array will result in 1000 0000 0000 0001, the exact opposite of the representation of bits in each byte.

Comment: It doesn't say that it store bytes by least significant bit first.
If I have file with size 2 bytes. byte[0] sholuld be covered by BitArray[0] to BitArray[7] and byte[1] from [8] to [15].

Comment: Please see in the example of myBA3 how number 4 is stored. Also your own example each byte is stored in reverse.

Comment: Lol you're right they are stored in reverse... Thats the whole problem.
Thank you! I should figure out clever way to revert them. Better during uploading the BitArray...

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. If you need more help, please comment and I will revise my answer.

Comment: Hm, I think they are printed in reverse because the `PrintValues` routine does just that: It __prints__ in reverse. The __storage__ is __not__ reversed,